# unable to loop through array using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular to consume nodejs web-service. 
But I am unable to loop through the data.

**Json Data:**

```
  [
  {
    "_id": "595fbe940eaeda0b387568fc",
    "randomId": "0001",
    "sName": "xyz abc",
    "des": "A wide variety of xyz abc",
    "__v": 0,
    "os": {
      "od": "2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z",
      "ok": "2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z",
      "dp": 10
    },
    "otherProductAttributes": {
      "l": "23",
      "mt": "fabricType"
    },
    "productStock": [
      {
        "size": 28,
        "color": "Red",
        "quantity": "120",
        "inStock": "true",
        "price": 234.56,
        "_id": "595fbe940eaeda0b387568ff",
        "imagePaths": [
          "https://image.jpg",
          "https://image.jpg",
          "https://image.jpg"
        ]
      },
      {
        "size": 28,
        "color": "Black",
        "quantity": "10",
        "inStock": "true",
        "price": 89,
        "_id": "595fbe940eaeda0b387568fe",
        "imagePaths": [
          "https://image.jpg"
        ]
      },
      {
        "size": 30,
        "color": "Red",
        "quantity": "999",
        "inStock": "true",
        "price": 999.99,
        "_id": "595fbe940eaeda0b387568fd",
        "imagePaths": [
          "https://image.jpg"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "uploadDate": "2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": "595fc0b60eaeda0b38756900",
    "randomId": "0002",
    "sName": "xyz abc",
    "des": "A wide variety of xyz abc",
    "__v": 0,
    "os": {
      "od": "2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z",
      "ok": "2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z",
      "dp": 10
    },
    "otherProductAttributes": {
      "l": "23",
      "mt": "fabricType"
    },
    "productStock": [
      {
        "size": 38,
        "color": "Red",
        "quantity": "120",
        "inStock": "true",
        "price": 234.56,
        "_id": "595fc0b60eaeda0b38756903",
        "imagePaths": [
          "https://image.jpg",
          "https://image.jpg",
          "https://image.jpg"
        ]
      },
      {
        "size": 26,
        "color": "Black",
        "quantity": "10",
        "inStock": "true",
        "price": 89,
        "_id": "595fc0b60eaeda0b38756902",
        "imagePaths": [
          "https://image.jpg"
        ]
      },
      {
        "size": 30,
        "color": "Red",
        "quantity": "999",
        "inStock": "true",
        "price": 999.99,
        "_id": "595fc0b60eaeda0b38756901",
        "imagePaths": [
          "https://image.jpg"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "uploadDate": "2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

**HTML Page**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getProducts()">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">Products</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-repeat="product in products">
             <p>{{product.randomId}}</p>
             <p>{{product.os.od}}</p>
             <p>{{product.otherProductAttributes.l}}</p>
             <p>{{prooduct.productStock.size}} </p>
             <p>{{prooduct.productStock.imagePaths}}</p>

              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to access above mentioned data fields, but html page is rendering nothing.
I printed products array on console, and it's printing entire array.So I HTML page is having data but it's not rendering according to my requirements.
Please help.

Comment: Your productStock is an array of objects, you have to refer to a particular index in your ng-repeat

Comment: @Vivz : yes , If try to access any field with **[subscript]**, then the value is getting rendered on the page.But how to iterate through entire product collection?. For example if i will do {{product[0].randomId}} , then it will print on the HTML page,but  otherwise nothing is printing in the page

Comment: You have to use one more ng-repeat

Comment: @Vivz : How can I use another ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use one more ng-repeat since `productStock` is an array of objects

```
 <div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        <p>{{product.randomId}}</p>
        <p>{{product.os.od}}</p>
        <p>{{product.otherProductAttributes.l}}</p>
        <div ng-repeat="value in product.productStock">
            <p>{{value.size}} </p>
            <div ng-repeat="image in value.imagePaths">
                <img ng-src="{{image}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still nothing is getting rendered on HTML page, don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you initialise the above projects with thejson?

Comment: Yup I am passing the JSON to HTML page

Comment: Are you using the second ng-repeat correctly? Post the code for getProducts?

Comment: This is my getProducts method 
`$scope.getProducts = function () { 
$http.get('/products/listProducts').then(function (res) { 
console.log(res); 
$scope.products = res; 

});`

Comment: It should be res.data that should be assigned to your products

Comment: One more thing ,I hhave imagePaths: ["https://image.jpg","https://image.jpg","https://image.jpg"],
How can Idisplay images individaually on the HTML page. ?

Comment: Use ng-src and you probably want to use one more ng-repeat for your imagePaths since it is an array again

Comment: But I don't have key for images,how to reference them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148683/discussion-between-vivz-and-mayank-bisht).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have nested ng-repeat to generate images from the stockPath.

```
 <div ng-repeat="images in product.productStock">
             <p>{{images.imagePaths}}</p>
 </div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.products = [
  {
    "_id": "595fbe940eaeda0b387568fc",
    "randomId": "0001",
    "sName": "xyz abc",
    "des": "A wide variety of xyz abc",
    "__v": 0,
    "os": {
      "od": "2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z",
      "ok": "2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z",
      "dp": 10
    },
    "otherProductAttributes": {
      "l": "23",
      "mt": "fabricType"
    },
    "productStock": [
      {
        "size": 28,
        "color": "Red",
        "quantity": "120",
        "inStock": "true",
        "price": 234.56,
        "_id": "595fbe940eaeda0b387568ff",
        "imagePaths": [
          "https://image.jpg",
          "https://image.jpg",
          "https://image.jpg"
        ]
      },
      {
        "size": 28,
        "color": "Black",
        "quantity": "10",
        "inStock": "true",
        "price": 89,
        "_id": "595fbe940eaeda0b387568fe",
        "imagePaths": [
          "https://image.jpg"
        ]
      },
      {
        "size": 30,
        "color": "Red",
        "quantity": "999",
        "inStock": "true",
        "price": 999.99,
        "_id": "595fbe940eaeda0b387568fd",
        "imagePaths": [
          "https://image.jpg"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "uploadDate": "2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": "595fc0b60eaeda0b38756900",
    "randomId": "0002",
    "sName": "xyz abc",
    "des": "A wide variety of xyz abc",
    "__v": 0,
    "os": {
      "od": "2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z",
      "ok": "2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z",
      "dp": 10
    },
    "otherProductAttributes": {
      "l": "23",
      "mt": "fabricType"
    },
    "productStock": [
      {
        "size": 38,
        "color": "Red",
        "quantity": "120",
        "inStock": "true",
        "price": 234.56,
        "_id": "595fc0b60eaeda0b38756903",
        "imagePaths": [
          "https://image.jpg",
          "https://image.jpg",
          "https://image.jpg"
        ]
      },
      {
        "size": 26,
        "color": "Black",
        "quantity": "10",
        "inStock": "true",
        "price": 89,
        "_id": "595fc0b60eaeda0b38756902",
        "imagePaths": [
          "https://image.jpg"
        ]
      },
      {
        "size": 30,
        "color": "Red",
        "quantity": "999",
        "inStock": "true",
        "price": 999.99,
        "_id": "595fc0b60eaeda0b38756901",
        "imagePaths": [
          "https://image.jpg"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "uploadDate": "2017-07-06T18:30:00.000Z"
  }
];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getProducts()">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">Products</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-repeat="product in products">
             <p>{{product.randomId}}</p>
             <p>{{product.os.od}}</p>
             <p>{{product.otherProductAttributes.l}}</p>                 
              <div ng-repeat="images in product.productStock">
             <p>{{images.size}} </p>
             <p>{{images.imagePaths}}</p>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if I write like this :product[0].randomId, then Id is getting printed on the HTML that too of 1st index.

Comment: Did you check the demo

Comment: @Sajwwtharan :Yup your demo working as per requirement ,but when I tried implementing same logic in my code, it's not working .

Comment: Is your data getting properly in controller?

Comment: What do you have inside getProducts method

Comment: Yes, I did console.log in my controller and it's showing product collection.Also if I print {{product}} in HTML page , it's also printing entire collection on the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148682/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: This is my getProducts method 

`$scope.getProducts = function () { 
$http.get('/products/listProducts').then(function (res) { 
console.log(res); 
$scope.products = res; 

});`

Answer (score 0):

Look well you have an inner array `productStock` in the object you are looping,so the way you are looping won't never work.

Assuming you have something in controller initialization-

```
$scope.products = [];    

Service.getData().then(function(response){      
       $scope.products = response;      
});
```

In html part introduce another ng-repeat to loop all stocks

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
   <p>{{product.randomId}}</p>
   <p>{{product.os.od}}</p>
   <p>{{product.otherProductAttributes.l}}</p>
    <div ng-repeat="pstock in product.productStock">          
        <p>{{pstock.size}} </p>
        <p>{{pstock.imagePaths}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```